# Match player stats add up to team stats in R

Tags: r

I have a dataset look like this and the example is part of the dataset. It includes all the player stats within a match of both teams. All I want is to add them up together into a team match stats instead. For example to add the number of kicks together for that match and become part of the team stats. As the date will keep continue for the whole season, all I wanted is just 1 date and add all the variables within the same date. Any idea how should I do it instead?

As head function only shows the first 10 rows in the data, this screenshot show the transition the player of the team form Home to Away.

[image]

```
> head(check_result,n=10)
# A tibble: 10 x 8
   Date       Home.team Away.team Home.score Away.score Surname   Kicks Playing.for
   <date>     <chr>     <chr>          <int>      <int> <chr>     <dbl> <chr>      
 1 2017-03-23 Carlton   Richmond          89        132 Armfield      1 Carlton    
 2 2017-03-23 Carlton   Richmond          89        132 Casboult      5 Carlton    
 3 2017-03-23 Carlton   Richmond          89        132 Cripps       10 Carlton    
 4 2017-03-23 Carlton   Richmond          89        132 Curnow        7 Carlton    
 5 2017-03-23 Carlton   Richmond          89        132 Curnow       13 Carlton    
 6 2017-03-23 Carlton   Richmond          89        132 Docherty     18 Carlton    
 7 2017-03-23 Carlton   Richmond          89        132 Gibbs        14 Carlton    
 8 2017-03-23 Carlton   Richmond          89        132 Kreuzer      11 Carlton    
 9 2017-03-23 Carlton   Richmond          89        132 Macreadie     3 Carlton    
10 2017-03-23 Carlton   Richmond          89        132 Marchbank    15 Carlton
```

Comment: So you want the sum of kicks per home team, but only one date (e.g. the first)?

Comment: Yeah am thinking to use aggregate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you are looking for. Using the `dplyr` package from the `tidyverse` you could aggregate your dataset using `group_by + summarise` or in case of only one variable using `count`. Both approaches will give you one row per date/match with the total number of kicks per team:

1. I also added a `filter()` to filter out (delete) rows where `Away.team == Playing.for`
2. If you have more variables to summarise you can add them to the vector `vars2sum`

```r
library(dplyr)

vars2sum <- c("Kicks")
check_result %>%
  # Filter out (delete) rows where Away.team == Playing.for
  filter(!Away.team == Playing.for) %>% 
  group_by(Date, Home.team, Away.team, Home.score, Away.score, Playing.for) %>%
  summarise(across(all_of(vars2sum), ~ sum(.x, na.rm = TRUE), .names = "{.col}.team")) %>% 
  select(-Playing.for)
#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'Date', 'Home.team', 'Away.team', 'Home.score', 'Away.score' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 6
#> # Groups:   Date, Home.team, Away.team, Home.score, Away.score [1]
#>   Date       Home.team Away.team Home.score Away.score Kicks.team
#>   <chr>      <chr>     <chr>          <int>      <int>      <int>
#> 1 2017-03-23 Carlton   Richmond          89        132         97
```

In case of just one variable you could also do:

```r
check_result %>%
      count(Date, Home.team, Away.team, Home.score, Away.score, Playing.for, wt = Kicks, name = "Kicks.team") %>% 
      select(-Playing.for)
    #>         Date Home.team Away.team Home.score Away.score Kicks.team
    #> 1 2017-03-23   Carlton  Richmond         89        132         97
```

**Data**

```r
check_result <- structure(list(Date = c(
  "2017-03-23", "2017-03-23", "2017-03-23",
  "2017-03-23", "2017-03-23", "2017-03-23", "2017-03-23", "2017-03-23",
  "2017-03-23", "2017-03-23"
), Home.team = c(
  "Carlton", "Carlton",
  "Carlton", "Carlton", "Carlton", "Carlton", "Carlton", "Carlton",
  "Carlton", "Carlton"
), Away.team = c(
  "Richmond", "Richmond",
  "Richmond", "Richmond", "Richmond", "Richmond", "Richmond", "Richmond",
  "Richmond", "Richmond"
), Home.score = c(
  89L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 89L,
  89L, 89L, 89L, 89L, 89L
), Away.score = c(
  132L, 132L, 132L, 132L,
  132L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 132L, 132L
), Surname = c(
  "Armfield",
  "Casboult", "Cripps", "Curnow", "Curnow", "Docherty", "Gibbs",
  "Kreuzer", "Macreadie", "Marchbank"
), Kicks = c(
  1L, 5L, 10L,
  7L, 13L, 18L, 14L, 11L, 3L, 15L
), Playing.for = c(
  "Carlton",
  "Carlton", "Carlton", "Carlton", "Carlton", "Carlton", "Carlton",
  "Carlton", "Carlton", "Carlton"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "1",
  "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"
))
```

Comment: I actually have more than one variable, so what I did was to continue the code, but R will won't be able to find variable halfway and stop. For example, I can run another 3 variables after Kick.team and it couldn't find the next one anymore. Any idea? I am able to run the code again with the variable that R said it couldn't find on another separate code.

Comment: I found a way to do it using summaries_all,
how about if I want to delete all the row where the condition is (Away.Team = Playing.for)?

Comment: @OMGC In case of multiple variables my preferred way would be to use `summarise` and `across` (see my edit), but you can go on with your approach. Always the best way to learn is to fgure out a solution yourself. To drop rows you can add a filter statement.